# Update statement using current value of the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update a row in a table by incrementing by one the integer value of one of the field..

The current doesn't work, why?

```
Update htmIndex SET numObs = numObs+1 where ...
```

Comment: Can't see why what you have shouldn't work - perhaps there's something in the WHERE clause we need to see?

Comment: That should definitely work... odd

Comment: Can you post the "WHERE" clause?

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer

Comment: In what way doesn't it work... throws an error, or the old value is still visible in the current session, or only in another session? If another session, just to rule out the obvious, have you committed the update?

Comment: I give the correct answer and the points are given to somebody else. thanks

Comment: @Rene, I'll upvote you :) but get used to it. Happens all the time. SO is not a contest or a race.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple case, update one row:

```
SQL> select name
  2         , age
  3  from t23
  4  where id = 2
  5  /

NAME                AGE
------------ ----------
MR KNOX              47

SQL> update t23
  2  set age = age + 6
  3  where id = 2
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select name
  2         , age
  3  from t23
  4  where id = 2
  5  /

NAME                AGE
------------ ----------
MR KNOX              53

SQL>
```

Update a row when the column has a null value:

```
SQL> select name
  2         , age
  3  from t23
  4  where id = 6
  5  /

NAME                AGE
------------ ----------
SALLY

SQL> update t23
  2  set age=age+5
  3  where id = 6
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select name
  2         , age
  3  from t23
  4  where id = 6
  5  /

NAME                AGE
------------ ----------
SALLY

SQL> update t23
  2  set age = nvl(age,0) +5
  3  where id = 6
  4  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select name
  2         , age
  3  from t23
  4  where id = 6
  5  /

NAME                AGE
------------ ----------
SALLY                 5

SQL>
```

Equally straightforward when updating multiple rows:

```
 SQL> select name
   2         , age
   3  from t23
   4  where age > 20
   5  /

 NAME                AGE
 ------------ ----------
 MR KNOX              53
 FOX IN SOCKS         37
 CAT                  23
 LORAX               443

 SQL> update t23
   2  set age = age + 1
   3  where age > 20
   4  /

 4 rows updated.

 SQL> select name
   2         , age
   3  from t23
   4  where age > 20
   5  /

 NAME                AGE
 ------------ ----------
 MR KNOX              54
 FOX IN SOCKS         38
 CAT                  24
 LORAX               444

SQL>
```

Comment: @Rene - Sorry you feel that way.  Actually there were no posted answers when I started on my response.  You posted yours while I was still working on my, er, verbose answer.

Comment: Still helpful and a nice non copied, verbose answer.

Answer (score 6):

It should work. However if the current column value is null then + 1 will return null.

try: `Update htmIndex SET numObs = nvl(numObs,0)+1 where ...`